# How to find length of drop-down with mat-options with Selenium Webdriver with Python?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am dealing with drop-downs that were created with Angular JS. When I look at HTML, the drop-down options that I see have a tag  and not a standard . So when I try to figure out the drop-down length, the following standard approach doesn't work

```
 select = drowser.find_element_by_id(elementID))
 print len(select.options)
```

How else can I try to find out how many options my drop-down has?

**EDITED:** Below is an example of HTML:

[image]

Comment: Update the question with the relevant HTML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your element is not a HTML `select` tag and it's not possible to use Selenium's `Select` class on it. Instead get all elements with tag `mat-option` under `div.mat-select-content`:

```
 selectOptions = drowser.find_elements_by_css_selector("div.mat-select-content mat-option")
 print len(selectOptions)
```